# Javascript for processing arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have pre-existing two arrays on the webpage that I need to customize, one with strings and other with corresponding id's. I need to replaces the strings in array1 based on the information I get using array2.
I have problem looping through array1 as it only gives me length = 1 in all cases.Why so? Is there any better way to accomplish this task? I will appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

```
var arr1= [[ "Khyle", "Marlen", "Jose"]];
var arr2= [[ "51", "69","22"]];
//replace extra square brackets
 var str =  arr2.replace((/[\[[']+/g,'[');   
 str= str.replace((/[\]]']+/g,']');      
 var length = str.length, element = null; 
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            element = str[i];
        // Ajax call to get the info and load in arr1[i]
             arr1[i] = ajax-str
        }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `replace` a String method? You're calling it on an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got an array inside an array.
This is why the array length is 1.
It should be:

var arr1= [ "Khyle", "Marlen", "Jose"];

var arr2= [ "51", "69","22"];

or you could write arr1 = arr1.pop() to get the array outside of array.

Answer (score 2):

This is the reason why:

```
var arr1= [[ "Khyle", "Marlen", "Jose"]];
```

That dimensions out to the equivalent of `arr1[0][strings]`, or 2 dimensions.

so, element 0 will always have a length of 1.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting an array length of 1 is because you're using double brackets, and you only need one pair of brackets to define an array in Javascript.

Because of that, you're actually creating an array that holds a single element: another array which holds the strings "Khyle", "Marlen" and "Jose".